# How to print all rows using iterrows method in pandas module?

Tags: python, pandas

birthdays.csv contain data:

```
name,email,year,month,day
Vishal,abc@email.com,2002,11,22
Riya,xyz@mail.com,2003,11,22
```

```
with open("birthdays.csv", "r") as file:
    data = pandas.read_csv(file)
    birthdays_dict = {(row['month'], row['day']): row for (index, row) in data.iterrows()}
print(birthdays_dict)
```

output:

```
{(11, 22): name             Riya
email    xyz@mail.com
year             2003
month              11
day                22
Name: 1, dtype: object}
```

expecting to get both rows

I was trying to solve a question of printing data using iterrows.
But i could not print my first row .
Can anyone plz explain and give me how to print both rows using iterrows itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to include the code as text, not as a image. Make sure you reduced your code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because `birthdays_dict` is a dictionary. And keys in the dictionary are unique. While your `row['month'], row['day']` pair is the same in both rows, so the second row overrides the first row in `birthdays_dict`. You need to use a list or different key (e.x. `row['year'], row['month'], row['day']`).

Side note, you can use `read_csv` with file name instead of file:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
birthdays_dict = {(row['year'], row['month'], row['day']): row for (index, row) in data.iterrows()}
print(birthdays_dict)
```